# How long does it take for an uploaded file to a Google cloud bucket to go live

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a static site hosted on Google Cloud as per this article https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website-http

I need to update the index.html file, I uploaded a new version, that version has the updates in it, I checked the checkbox to say overwrite the file, Google Cloud says the upload was complete and it shows the date created as being today but the index.html that they serve does not have the changes.

Is there a time to changes are live that I'm unaware of or is there something else I need to do to make this file get overwritten?

on edit: The situation is resolved now, after approximately half an hour, I don't believe there was any client side caching at any rate I requested the site with FF developer and refreshed the page and did not see any changes. However when I went and checked the page in Safari it did show me the changed page, after which when I checked in FF Developer again it also showed the changed page. So this implies some sort of caching somewhere.

As far as correct blob cache metadata settings are concerned I did not configure any metadata for the file and it seems cache-control is not set.

Comment: Why do you think it is not live? Edit your question with details. If instead you mean the new version is not downloading, make sure you have the correct blob cache metadata settings. Also, make sure that your browser has not cached the old version.

Comment: Ok well it seems there is definitely a non-negligible time before changes go live, I don't know how much that varies or if it is potentially instantaneous, but in my case it was more than 20 minutes, less than 45.

Comment: New objects go live nearly instantly. Edit your question with the details that I asked for. Most likely you have a client-side caching problem. Note: once the object upload completes, it is no longer possible to access the old version except in special cases (versioning enabled, etc.).